# Broken Screenshots using Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, screenshot

I'm having a problem taking a screenshot when a dialog is showing.  I'm trying to take it from the emulator, and the problem is that only portions of the dialog show up, and other portions show through from behind.  Here is the emulator screenshot on the left, and one from my device on the right:

[image: Broken Screenshot] [image: Correct Screenshot]

I have tried running different API levels in the emulator, as well as both the ARM and Intel Atom images, none of which helped.  I even tried it on both my laptop and desktop to no avail.  Has anybody else run into this problem?

Comment: Is `Use host GPU` enabled? If it is, what happens if you turn it off? If it isn't, what happens if you turn it on?

Comment: Oh right, good question.  It is off, because when I turn it on all screenshots are simply black.

Comment: are you using genymotion emulator ?

Comment: No, I am using the one that comes with Android SDK Tools.  Genymotion looks like it's worth a look, though.

Comment: yes, me I use it, it is very fast, fast than real device for me in debugging